# Does the attention mechanism (in CNNs) bring additional parameters/weights to learn to the network?

Tags: neural-networks, attention

The idea of the attention mechanism is based on using some weighted sum of the output of some layers in deep networks. I see the process in forward propagation, and it seems that the attention mechanism does not bring additional weights to learn to the system. Do I get it right?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it does introduce more parameters. The original definition of attention (by [Bahdanau et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473)) defines attention energies as a single-layer NN computation:

$$e_i = v^T \tanh \left( Wq + Uk_i + b \right)$$

where $q$ is the query and $K=(k_1, \ldots,k_n)$ are the keys (using the later terminology of Attention is all you need), $v$, $W$ and $U$ are learnable parameters. The energies are later normalized using softmax and the resulting distribution is used to compute the context vector, i.e., a weighted average of some values.

When you assume, you can directly compare the keys and the query, you can compute the energies as $e_i = q^Tk_i$ with a single dot product. In that case, you indeed do not introduce further parameters to the model. However, this ofter works poorly, so there is a linear projection before the dot product (e.g., in the splitting the attention heads in the Transformers) to make the keys and queries commensurable, which, however, means additional hyperparamters.